# Async method exception crashing application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am using a third party DLL which offers an async method to perform an operation.

I run this inside a try-catch block but - with JustMyCode disabled - I get an error originating from somewhere inside the third party object which can only be handled in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, which closes the app and is far to generalised as a place to handle this.

The code:

```
try { ResultObject result = await thirdPartyObject.MethodAsync(); }
catch { /* never get here */ }
```

The signature of the thirdPartyObject.MethodAsync() from reflection:

```
public Task<ResultObject> MethodAsync();
```

After hitting the internal error (which is only visible with 'Just My Code' disabled in VS settings), it goes onto a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'A task was canceled.'
 ...

Is there a way to intercept that task cancellation without hitting the global unhandled exception handler?

Comment: `thirdPartyObject.MethodAsync().Result;` will do?

Comment: I've seen something similar with angularjs async http calls and deferred caches. You should contact the devs of the third party, maybe send a pull request.

Comment: I don't see a reason why that would not enter the catch block unless their code is bad which could be since their object is named "ResultObject".

Comment: @Crowcoder funnily enough the method name is renamed for this question, so don't get hung up on the method name.  This is more about the exception behaviour.

Comment: Not the method name, the name of the return Type. Did you also change that? It would be poor API design to name something so generically.

Comment: Can you comb through their decompiled code and see if they are calling any async void methods?

Comment: Question updated with a bit more detail.  Return type also renamed just for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to intercept that task cancellation without hitting the global unhandled exception handler?

Not without catching the exception in the third-party code. If the third-party method for example starts a new thread, or a new `Task` which it doesn't await, and an exception is thrown on this background thread, it won't get catched by your `catch` clause code.

Please refer to @Peter Torr's blog post for more information and some examples: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/

You should really ask the manufacturer of the assembly to fix their code.

Comment: This is correct - there is no way to solve this without fixing the 3rd party code (which has now been done, happily!)

Comment: I'm getting exception from mono runtime in http secure handling. Would be nice, If I can prevent app crash. https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/8350